# Java concurrency: Modifying latch/ThreadGroup to achieve Executor behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executorservice, countdownlatch

This question is related to my homework assignment in Java concurrency topic. I have been tasked to spawn new threads and limit them by a given `concurrencyFactor`. That is, keep on dispatching new threads until number of active threads is less than or equal to `concurrencyFactor`. If the number of active threads is equal to `concurrencyFactor`, program will wait until number of active threads reduce to `concurrencyFactor - 1` and create a new one.

As a first approach, I am using `ExecutorService` and created a new fixed pool by `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(concurrencyFactor);` and whenever my method is called, I am just submitting a new runnable to this pool. Code for the logic is below:

```
    private final ExecutorService fixedPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(concurrencyFactor);
    public void handleRequest(final RequestHandler handler) {
    if (handler == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Handler cannot be null");
    fixedPoolExecutor.submit(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.serviceRoutine();
        }
      });
    }
```

Now, the second part asks me to achieve the same goal but without using executor. I have thought of following two approaches:
1)  Use `countDownLatch` but this latch would wait(i.e. `latch.await()`) until `activeCount` becomes `0`. I want to wait only till the countDown becomes `concurrencyFactor - 1`.
2) Use `ThreadGroup` and wait until `threadGroup.activeCount() < concurrencyFactor`. But, the problem with this approach is how can I make the incoming request wait until the condition  `threadGroup.activeCount() < concurrencyFactor` meets? I have used the below code for this approach:

```
    private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup("myGroup");
    public void handleRequest(final RequestHandler handler) {
    if (handler == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Handler cannot be null");
    lock.lock();
    try {
        while (threadGroup.activeCount() >= concurrencyFactor) {

        }
        Thread t = new Thread(threadGroup, new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.service();
            }
        });
        t.start();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }        
   }
```

Can I replace the blank while loop with some wait condition in the second approach?

Any suggestions on above approaches or advice for any new approach would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the assignment force you to use CountDownLatch?

Comment: No it doesn't force. But the instructions hint to achieve this using Latches/Threads/Executors.

Comment: Because this seems a great fit for Semaphore.

Comment: The problem is: When can I call semaphore.release()? I have to know number of currently active threads.

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using `Sempahore`. The semaphore would represent the number of threads still allowed to be started. Initially it holds permits equal to the configured concurrency factor.

Before starting a new thread, the handleRequest method needs to acquire a permit from the semaphore. The threads that are started should, upon completion release that permit again.

Sample code :

```
private final ThreadGroup threadGroup = new ThreadGroup("myGroup");
private final Semaphore concurrencyFactor = new Semaphore(CONCURRENCY_FACTOR);

public void handleRequest(final RequestHandler handler) throws InterruptedException {
    if (handler == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Handler cannot be null");

    concurrencyFactor.acquire(); // Get permit

    Thread t = new Thread(threadGroup, new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                handler.service();
            } finally {
                concurrencyFactor.release(); // make sure to release permit
            }
        }
    });
    t.start();
}
```

(you may want to deal differently with possible interruption)

Comment: Does the try block inside the run method ensure that the `concurrencyFactor` is released only after the `service` method is run to completion?

Comment: It ensures the permit is released despite any exceptions thrown in service()

Comment: If we use semaphore, then why to use `threadGroup` in that case? Doesn't that cause unnecessary group management overhead?

Comment: ThreadGroup doesn't help solve the question. I kept it in because I thought you wanted it for some reason.

Comment: Great! Really appreciate your help.